# Path type for PHP opendir()

Tags: php

Seems a little bit of an odd question to be asking. What path does opendir() expect?

When I try: `opendir('/home/myuser/public_html');` and get this `[function.opendir]: failed to open dir: No such file or directory`.

If that path isn't correct, what should it be?

Comment: The syntax you use is fine. The path either doesn't exist, or the PHP user doesn't have the right to access it. http://php.net/opendir

Comment: maybe it because `No such file or directory` ? xD

Comment: The directory does exist, so I guess this is a permissions issue. Just tried with a different directory and it worked ... @Pekka, can you write an answer please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax you use is fine. (see the [PHP Manual on opendir)](http://php.net/opendir)

The path either doesn't exist, or the PHP user doesn't have the right to access it.

Comment: Proper head in hands moment, I was logged into the wrong FTP account so the folder didn't actually exist on the domain I was testing this on... DOH!

Answer (score 0):

You should use relative paths.. For example: If your PHP App resides in `/opt/project` 
then you should use it as `('../../home/myuser/public_html')`

Comment: Why? There is no difference between relative and absolute paths, except that the former can cause more trouble when moving stuff across directories. I don't see how this helps the OP's problem?

Comment: @Pekka: i would delete my answer if it leads to wrong conclusion,i meant to say that the user could also use the relative paths also if he faced any problems with absolute

Comment: @Pekka One _should_ use relative paths, even though absolute path works fine.

Comment: @stef I'd say that depends massively on the situation.

Comment: @Pekka - In what situation would you want your code to be not easily portable?

Comment: @stefgosselin you realize we are talking about file system paths, not web paths? For the latter, I agree with you. For filesystem paths, it often doesn't make sense - when you work with a specific configured path like `/home/myuser/public_html` that you fetch stuff from, using relative paths actually makes portability *harder*

Comment: @Pekka Yes, filesystem paths. Hardcoding absolute path in an application creates a dependency. The way I was taught is 1. Using php to get the absolute path is the best way to go.  Many ways to do this with `_DIR_` and realpath() for example. 2. Using relative path second best, of course include_path needs to be properly configured but again this can be done in the same script with set_include_path(). 3. Hard-coded absolute path work too,  but are less portable as your application depends on the filesystem layout to work.  Of course, I could be wrong and please correct me if I am.

Comment: @stef this is all correct if the path used *makes sense* as a relative path. i.e. if the other path is part of the same "package" as the current one, like inside the same application or web site. But if the other path is a completely unrelated one, outside the "package", it is better to use absolute paths - the dependency is there *anyway* (if you move to a different system, you will probably have to adjust the path), and using an absolute path means that you can freely move the file using it. Relative paths make sense only if there is an actual relation

Comment: @Pekka - I see your point,  and I cannot say it is 'wrong' though I would never be allowed to this in the projects I work on. For example. if I implement feature 'w' and need a 3rd party lib 'xyz', I would be required to either put 'xyz' inside package 'w', _or_ at location /usr/local/lib/php_web/w ,  /usr/local/lib/php_web being set in include path. Your are totally right this is still a dependency. How this dependency is handled is probably a matter of preference.